# Python: regex to extract location from the hostname

Tags: python, regex

I would like to extract the location from the following possible hostnames:

> webeu01, dbus01a, lbus

This will work with the first two examples:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'(.*)(\w{2})(\d{2})([a-b]?)', 'webeu01').group(2)
'eu'
>>> re.search(r'(.*)(\w{2})(\d{2})([a-b]?)', 'dbus01a').group(2)
'us'
```

The third one only works if I make the group with digits optional:

```
>>> re.search(r'(.*)(\w{2})(\d{2})?([a-b]?)', 'lbus').group(2)
'us'
```

but this breaks the other two:

```
>>> re.search(r'(.*)(\w{2})(\d{2})?([a-b]?)', 'webeu01').groups()
('webeu', '01', None, '')
```

Is it possible to do this with a single RegEx or do I need to split this into two and then check it with a function like [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#any)

Comment: How would you want a regex to handle `lbusa` ?  On what basis would it know to do that?

Comment: The location is always two-letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
r'^(.*?)(\w{2})(?:(\d{2})([ab]?))?$'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/75bXQB/3)

The point is that

- You need to match the whole string, and that means you must add anchors around the pattern, `^` and `$`
- You need to make the `\d{2}` group optional, so, either add `?` or wrap it with an optional non-capturing group.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than linebreak chars as few as possible
- `(\w{2})` - two word chars
- `(?:(\d{2})([ab]?))?` - an optional non-captruring groyup msatching

  - `(\d{2})` - Group 2: any two digits
  - `([ab]?)` - Group 3: an optional `a` or `b`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: thanks. It works great but there is a corner case if any letter from the last group matches, for instance `gb`: `>>> re.search(r'^(.*?)(\w{2})((?:\d{2})?)([ab]?)$', 'lbgb').groups()
('l', 'bg', '', 'b')`

Comment: @HTF Then how do you want to delimit the captures? What are their specifications? Try `^(.*?)(\w{2})(?:(\d{2})([ab]?))?$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/75bXQB/3).

Comment: These are the only possible options `webeu01, dbus01a, lbus` but location can be `gb` so ` webgb01, dbgb01a, dbgb01b, lbgb` are all possible

Comment: @HTF Ok, I included the `[ab]?` pattern into the optional non-capturing group and it is only ossible to match it after digits.